# Second order low pass filter with three op amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, low-pass, active-filter

Why is the node voltage at (1) equal to \$s^2(\tau)^2V_{\text{out}}\$?

[image: 3 op-amp LPF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the path from \$V_1\$ to \$V_{\text{out}}\$. We have two integrators cascaded, so:

$$
V_{\text{out}}(s)=\left(\frac{-1}{s\tau}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{s\tau}\right)V_1(s)=\frac{1}{s^2\tau^2}V_1(s)
$$

After inverting it, we get:

$$
V_1(s)=s^2\tau^2V_{\text{out}}(s)
$$

We simply worked backwards from the output.